# What is proper word for "His words vibrated in my ears"

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, sentence

What is the proper way of saying

```
His words vibrated in my ears
```

The context is a man calls some one for the last time.He is about to die.What ever the other person says he cannot hear clearly but kind of echoes in his ears

Comment: You may get better answers if you provide more context, like the speaker, audience, situation, medium, etc. By “proper” do you mean idiomatic? technically correct? grammatical? evocative? There are countless ways to say this, and many of them would be considered proper, depending on the context.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung updated question

Comment: In addition to TJY's advice, you may want to try "a good way of saying" rather than "the proper way to say." "The proper way" implies that there is one "proper" way to say something, and all the other ways are not "proper" for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

[Resonate](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/resonate) -

1. produce or be filled with a deep, full, reverberating sound
2. evoke or suggest images, memories, and emotions

Answer (score 3):

His words echoed in my ears.  Vibrated would not really be used there.

Answer (score 3):

What about reverberated?  That could work.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't 'ringing' the word you are searching?

Comment: _Rang_ is also the first thing that came to my mind.